# Reversing lists of numbers in python

Tags: python, list

So I have been trying to do this for a while now and am constantly coming up with differing failures. I need to take numerical input from the user and put it into a list and output it in decreasing value:

```
bids = []
bid = input('Bid: ')
while bid != '':
  bids.append(bid)
  bid = input('Bid: ')
print('The auction has finished! The bids were:')

for bid in bids:
  bid = int(bid)

for bid in reversed(bids):
 print(bid)
```

So this worked well most of the time, (I have been using the numbers 2,3,4 & 10 as input as I have been having problems where it shows the numbers in decreasing order for the first numeral) but when I type in 16, 30, 24 it displays the numbers as:

```
The auction has finished! The bids were:
24
30
16
```

Here is another version I have attempted:

```
bids = []
bid = input('Bid: ')
while bid != '':
  bids.append(bid)
  bid = input('Bid: ')
print('The auction has finished! The bids were:')

for bid in bids:
  bid = int(bid)

bids.sort([::-1]) #Here is where the problem is at, I don't know
                  #what the correct syntax is for something like that

for bid in bids:
  print(bid)
```

Any help will be much appreciated as I am fairly new to python and am struggling with my course.

-Callum

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? `input` does very different things in each.

Comment: @CPastuszak Run `python --version`

Comment: @Daenyth its python 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your

```
bids.append(bid)
```

you get a list of strings. You want to convert them to integers and sort in decreasing order:

```
numerical_bids = [int(bid) for bid in bids]
numerical_bids.sort(reverse=True)
```

and now `numerical_bids` is a list of integers sorted in decreasing order.

In your code:

```
for bid in bids:
    bid = int(bid)
```

does nothing. It converts each `bid` to an integer and forgets it immediately.

And

```
bids.sort([::-1])
```

is not how to use the `sort` method. Read the docs for [list.sort](http://www).

Comment: Thank you so very much, but how would I get it to print the sorted list out in a vertical format like the ones above and not in list format

Comment: @Copperfield But I don't understand where to insert the for loop

Comment: If list of bids is not enormous, you can do it like that: print('\n'.join(bids))

Comment: @CPastuszak you want to print the sorted list, right? then first do that as @eumiro show you and then do like you do in the lasts line of the code you show us, that is `for bid numerical_bids: print(bid)`

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks yeah I did what you said and its working, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is fundamentally in this loop:

```
for bid in bids:
  bid = int(bid)
```

The above does not alter the contents of `bids`. It creates new integer instances, named `bid` each time, which you don't do anything with. So when you later go to sort `bids`, you are just sorting the original string elements, not your desired integers.

If you want to sort the integer values, you have a few choices. One is to convert the values to integers as they come in:

```
bids.append(int(bid))
```

One is to convert and sort right in your print loop:

```
for bid in sorted((int(x) for x in bids), reverse=True):
  print(bid)
```

Since the approach you seemed to want to take is to replace the string elements of `bids` with integer elements instead, you probably want to do something like your original loop, but don't throw away the results:

```
intbids = []
for bid in bids:
    intbids.append(int(bid))
```

Lots of folks will tell you that the above is more concisely written as

```
intbids = [int(bid) for bid in bids]
```

I used `intbids` as a separate list to make it clear what is happening. If you want to just throw away the string bid list once you have the integer bid list, you can just use the same name:

```
bids = [int(bid) for bid in bids]
```

If it's really, really important to do the replacement of each element "in place" (meaning don't create a new list), then the simplest-to-understand way is probably to loop over the indices:

```
for i in range(len(bids):
    bids[i] = int(bids[i])
```

(But until you are very experienced and working with tons and tons of data, my strong recommendation is to not worry about "in-place" updating of lists. It's not as natural a way to write Python.)

Answer (score 2):

This will sort for you list of bids in form of numeric strings, in reversed, numerical order:

```
bids.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
```

And if you need to print it vertically:

```
print('\n'.join(bids))
```

Comment: This will sort the bids, but leave them as strings, which is probably not intended.

Comment: Well, I have tried to answer the question and help the person who asked it to understand Python better. I do not think that people answering questions should speculate about intensions if they were not expressed explicitly in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me explain:
You're not sorting your inputs!

In your second case, your list is `[16,30,24]` and you're printing it in reverse order `24, 30, 16` which is correct.

I see two problems:
- you're not sorting the values for printing
- you're not checking if the new bid is higher than the previous one (what kind of bidding is that?)

For the first part, asuming the the list already contains `int`, you just have to sort it:

```
bids.sort()
```

Or if you you want it in the reverse order:

```
bids.sort(reverse=True)
```

For the second part, just check if the new input is bigger before adding it to the list:

```
while bid != '':
    if bids and bid < bids[-1]:
        print "Error: your bid must be higher than last bid. Last bid: {}".format(bids[-1])
    else:
        bids.append(bid)
    bid = input('Bid: ')
```